# Ajax Request in Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am very new to Angular js. I am trying to alert in angular and want to send ajax request to node server .

Here is code which i tried so far.

As my alert in not working

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
            <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="#">
            <input type="text" ng-model="url">
            <input type="button" ng-click="a()" value="Click here"/>                
  </div>
    </form>

    <script>

        function a() {
            alert("Hello");
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are actually not using angular as you are missing ng-app directive. I suggest you spend 1-2 hours on angular basic.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html ng-app> .........

<body ng-controller="personController">
<form action="#">
        <input type="text" ng-model="url">
        <input type="button" ng-click="a()" value="Click here"/>                
</form>
<script>
  function personController($scope) {
     $scope.a = function() {
          alert("Hello");
     }    
  }
</script>
```

here is the [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SQWCrbcracMAhpingNG3?p=preview)